# How to deploy a .war file AND a jni library file onto a web server?

Tags: tomcat, heroku, intellij-idea, java-native-interface, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy my application onto a web server online (so far I've been using heroku, but I'm open to other services).

I'm using `IntelliJ` and made a Spring application (running using Tomcat 7). One of the requirements of my application is that I run some `C` code. I have researched JNI and was successful in compiling a `.so` library out of my `C` code.

Everything works perfectly locally. To have `IntelliJ` correctly load the `.so` library, I put it inside the `bin/` directory of `IntelliJ` (I think there are also ways of using a VM option `-Djava.library.path` to direct `Tomcat` to the directory with the .so file).

My question is: how should I proceed to try to put my application online somewhere knowing that I need Tomcat to load a JNI library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not wise to use JNI under a web server stack; If any of the native code bombs, it will bring down the entire web server.

If you absolutely need your native code, an alternative is to run that code as a standalone application, with an exposed RMI interface.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll keep in mind RMI for the future. However, you did not answer my question about what exactly I should be doing. Right now I'm playing around `Amazon's EC2`.

Comment: @ijkilchenko You can query the system's library path `System.getProperty("java.library.path")`.  Maybe its a location that Amazon EC2 will allow you to drop files off at.